# Regex to extract value from a predefined String formats

Tags: java, regex

I'm new to generating regex. I know we can use Pattern & Matcher classes to compile and find the regex from a String. 
But i'm not sure how to create the regex for my problem, which is as below.
  Example, if String str = "T2(123)", then my regex should return 123, where T2 is going to be constant always, only value=123 going to change.
Similarly, if String str = "T2(23)K3(11)", then it should return 23+11 = 34, where T2 and K3 are constants.

I'm thinking of making String T2(#) and T2(#)K3(#) as my tokens and comparing my input string with this tokens and returning the value of # or sum(#).

But not sure how to do the same using regex.

```
int sum = 0;
String type = "T2(23)";
String pttrn = "(?<=T2\\()\\d+(?=\\))";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pttrn);
Matcher m = p.matcher(type);

while (m.find()) {
    sum += Integer.parseInt(m.group());
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

I have tried the above code and it returns 23, but it is not working for T2(#)K3(#) type.

Comment: Maybe `String pttrn = "(?<=T2\\(|K3\\()\\d+(?=\\))";`? Or just `String pttrn = "(?:T2|K3)\\((\\d+)\\)";` and then grab `m.group(1)`?

Comment: What kind of numbers can go in the brackets? Can it be with a decimal place e.g. 1.1? Can it be negative e.g. -10?

Comment: @Sweeper It will only have positive integer numbers. Neither negative nor decimal number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you just want the numbers inside parentheses, and ignore the rest, so:

`\((\d+)\)`

```
static void test(String input) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\((\\d+)\\)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    int sum = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("T2(23)");             // prints: 23
    test("T2(123)");            // prints: 123
    test("T2(23)K3(11)");       // prints: 34
    test("T2(23)K3(11)U4(42)"); // prints: 76
}
```

<sup>Note: The above regex is following the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) ("keep it simple, stupid").</sup>

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, it worked. I have tried this pattern earlier but was fetching m.group() and thus getting (23) numbers with parentheses. Now, I checked m.group(1). It working as I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generalization without using lookarounds:

```
String input = "T2(23)K3(11)U4(42)";
// matches 1 uppercase alphabetic, 1 digit, and 
// back-references any length digit sequence between parenthesis (excluded)
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{Upper}\\d\\((\\d+)\\)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
int total = 0;
// iterates occurrences and sums
while (matcher.find()) {
    // this is safe as group 1 will always be a digit sequence
    // not safe from arithmetic overflows though
    total += Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Your total would be `76` here.

**Note**

As posted by Andreas, a looser requirement (only digits between parenthesis) begets a simpler pattern.